# Surface Pro 3 typecover not working!

Tags: 15.10

I would just like to put it out there that I am a complete noob on Linux but, I am open to learn. So here is the problem I am having:

I installed of Ubuntu 15.10 on my Surface Pro 3 (Dual-boot). After the install my wireless, bluetooth, volume buttons & trackpad all work 100% fine except for the actual keyboard. I can type anything but nothing will happen anywhere. Please help!